# How do you set up headset/mike communications for GTA V online with ps3?

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

I have a PS3 and would like to communicate with other online GTA V players. How does this work? Can I use a Bluetooth headset with mike? do I need special software?

Answer (score 1):

PS3 natively supports bluetooth.

Before you can use the Bluetooth headset with any device, such as the PS3 or a mobile phone, the headset must be paired to the desired device.

**You can pair the headset in two ways:**

**Automatic mode** (using the supplied USB cable) - Enables the headset's advanced features for the PS3. Using automatic mode, you can pair the headset with any PS3, but only the most recently paired PS3 will be saved in the headset's list of paired devices.
Click here for more information on the advanced features of the Bluetooth headset.

**Bluetooth discovery mode** - Sets up the headset as a standard Bluetooth headset. By using Bluetooth discovery mode you can pair the headset with many other Bluetooth devices.

https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1226

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with others for PSN just go to `Accessory setting -> Manage Bluetooth Devices` and scan your headset type. Then go back to `Accessory Settings -> Audio Device Settings`. Make sure that the microphone level is at 5 and the input and output settings match the type of your headset.